# Angular ngrx store understanding the return value from Reselect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to wrap my head around what is going under the hood when using reselect with store.select() from ngrx.

I know that the select() method expects you to return the piece from the state you want to return. For example:

```
store.select(state => state.articles.isLoading);
```

With Reselect it would be something like:

```
// articles.reducer
const getIsLoading = state => state.isLoading

// root.ts
const getArticlesState = state => state.articles;
const getIsLoading = createSelector(getArticlesState, fromArticles.getIsLoading)

//component.ts
store.select(fromRoot.getIsLoading)
```

I am trying to understand what is happening in the final piece:

```
store.select(fromRoot.getIsLoading)
```

`fromRoot.getIsLoading` returns a value or a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [reselect documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect):

> Selectors are efficient. A selector is not recomputed unless one of its arguments change

Also, you should read that: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#motivation-for-memoized-selectors

That said, `reselect` uses a process called `memoization` internally. So what's happening is that it saves the output of your selector, and every time the selector is triggered, it checks if the parameters passed to the selector are the same, and if they are, `reselect` just returns the cached result, instead of going through and computing again your data.

That's why this lib is really interesting if you normalize your data and then need to compose them with selectors.

Also, as your array/objects composed by your selectors won't change their references when `reselect` returns the cached values, Angular can use that information and avoid to trigger a repaint. Which is of course, faster than repainting everything when your store is updated.

Answer (score 0):

selector `getIsLoading` returns a value. Its where that value comes from that's important.

selector keeps cached the last value it returned. also, it keeps track if the slice of the store thats a parameter for its transform function changed or not.

If the store changed, it will re-run transform function, cache the value it got and return it.

If the store didn't change, it will return cached value directly.